# OroCRM makes my hosting server slow down?

Tags: server, magento-1.9, orocrm

I am using Magento 1.9 and configured OroCRM, most of time my site down or keep loading 1 hour because OroCRM takes server resource,

10-0 10440 0/1/79166 W 0.00 7 0 147924407 0.0 0.04 2121.58 66.248.202.18 http/1.1 abc.in:443 POST /index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ HTTP/1.1

FYI here **W** means **Sending Reply.**

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are no general recommendations for performance optimization as it depends on many factors, like the amount of data in a database, code customizations, number of visitors, list of features you are using the most and so on.

First, make sure the webserver meets [OroCRM system requirements](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/system-requirements/). These requirements are applied only to the OroCRM application, so if you have multiple applications configured on the same server, you should increase resources accordingly.
If requirements are met, the next step would be increasing available resources. Most of the time it's the easiest way to solve the performance issue.

When it doesn't help you can go with performance profiling tools, like checking SQL server slow logs, using blackfire.io to profile certain requests that are slow and so on.

Comment: After upgrade PHP version crm not wokring, can i get help  @https://forum.oroinc.com/orocrm/topic/orocrm-not-working-after-upgrade-php-version/